# Get data from advertising Facebook account from Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want automatically collect data from fb ad account with marketing api.

There is an facebook app, which has access to advertising account (with access level = development). App has product 'Marketing API'.

Got access_token (app_id|token) like this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<secret>7&grant_type=client_credentials
```

When i try insights method

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_<ad_account_id>/insights/?access_token=<access_token>
```

i got an error

```
"message": "Unsupported get request.", "type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate not app token, but user token of someone who has access to that ad account.